# how to answer 'yes' in this code

Tags: python-2.7

I have seen this code in a book.according to this book,as we run code and type 'classMaker()' will see this:

> > > classMaker()

making the class

### do you want to make an object of the class?

and then we answer:yes,

> > > classMaker()

making the class

do you want to make an object of the class?

yes

object made

### your name is Raman

I don't understand how to enter 'yes'.what should I do?Do I write 'yes' after '....of the class?'?
I did that but It failed

```
 def classMaker(flag=True):
 if flag:
 print('making the class')
 class MyName:
 name='Raman'
 print('do you want to make an object of the class?')
 answer=input()
 if answer=='yes':
 my_object=MyName()
 print('object made')
 print('your name is',my_object.name
```

Comment: Also, your code isn't formatted properly - because as is, that will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
answer = raw_input('Do you want to make an object of the class?')
```

Why?

> raw_input() asks the user for a string of data (ended with a newline),
>   and simply returns the string. It can also take an argument, which is
>   displayed as a prompt before the user enters the data.

Whilst:

> input() uses raw_input to read a string of data, and then attempts to
>   evaluate it as if it were a Python program, and then returns the value
>   that results.

Now you can parse the answer to determine if it contains 'yes'.

REFERENCE: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output#Examples

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you get an error when you do that if you use one of the Python 2.x versions. In Python 2.x, `input()` expects a Python expression, not just any string. So in your case your name is probably interpreted by Python as a variable and returns a `NameError` error. If that's the case, just provide your input as a string. That means use `""`.